# What's a free alternative to SlideShowPro?

Tags: software, photo-galleries, slideshow

I'm looking for a free alternative to [SlideShowPro](http://slideshowpro.net/) for a client, preferable open source and a solution that doesn't use Flash, but rather use JavaScript with deploy similar techniques as on Flickr for protecting (c) material?

I have taken a peek on [Gallery](http://gallery.menalto.com/) which looks very interesting. Any other options?

Thank you.

Comment: As this question is really about webdesign you might find a better answer on doctype.com (which is affiliated with stackoverflow)

Comment: Thanks Matt, but I think it's better to have photographers opinions over web designers when it comes to presentation of pictures.

Comment: Do you know about Jalbum (http://jalbum.net)? I have no idea what your requirements are but you should check it out. It is very versatile and easy to use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a lot. Here are a links to a few pages of interest:

- [The Lightbox Clones Matrix](http://planetozh.com/projects/lightbox-clones/)
- [Nivo Slider](http://nivo.dev7studios.com/)
- [Galleria](http://galleria.aino.se/)
- [GalleryView](http://spaceforaname.com/galleryview)
- [SmoothGallery 2.0](http://smoothgallery.jondesign.net/)
- [(E)2 Photo Gallery](http://www.e2interactive.com/e2_photo_gallery/)
- [The Top: 12 Best jQuery Image Galleries](http://www.devlounge.net/design/the-top-12-best-jquery-image-galleries)
- [20 Professional jQuery Image Gallery Plugins](http://speckyboy.com/2009/12/03/20-professional-jquery-image-gallery-plugins/)